# debugging javascript in VS 2012 - localhost cache has old code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

I am starting to build a PhoneGap app and decided to use VS2012 as an editor/debugger because Eclipse & XCode don't do javascript debugging (or do they, maybe I missed something) and VS2012 has intellisense for js. Having copied all the html and js files into a VS2012 project, the code ran fine. But then I made an edit, and the debugger won't now stop at a breakpoint on the edited line - there is an error message " adifferent version of this script file has been loaded by the debug process" . It also says "for Windows Store Apps, use 'Debug-Refresh Windows app' - but this isn't a Windows Store App (well not yet anyway!) - the code appears to be running from a localhost cache that has the previous version of my source, even after rebooting the PC.
Any idea what to do?
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 6):

Ok, solved - just need to do a  CTRL+F5 from the browser to reload the new code.

Comment: Hope this works for me too, I've been remembering the good old early days of Silverlight working with my mvc4/html/javascript app. Trying to get updated code up to the browser has been a bear.