# Older (maybe cached) version of javascript file shown while debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I have made changes to a javascript file and while I am executing and debugging, it is showing me the older version of the file. I tried all the solutions given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807238/debugging-javascript-in-vs-2012-localhost-cache-has-old-code) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739434/visual-studio-2013-caching-older-version-of-js-file) links but none of them worked for me. I am using VS 2013 on Win 8.1 and IE 11.

Things I tried :

1) Ctrl + F5

2) Clear browser cache

3) Rebuild Solution

4) Restart VS

5) Restart IIS

6) Clear Temporary ASP.NET Files

7) Restart machine

Still its showing the same older version. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out the problem and its pretty weird one. I was just going through the Windows Update history and found out that today Windows have released a new [Update for IE 11 - KB3025390](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025390) which had got installed on my PC too through automatic updates. I uninstalled this update and debugged my application and it started referring the latest versions of javascript file.

Just in case it helps anyone in future.

Comment: I know this is off topic, but I feel sorry for you losing time debugging something that wasn't your fault. Making webpage work ie makes me re-evaluate my decisions every time.

Comment: Ya it really was nothing related to programming, it really is a waste of productive time. However, we can't really blame MS, can we?